# openmp falsesharing or datarace or wtf?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have these 2 structs:

```
typedef struct{ 

    int id;
    double label;
    double coord[30];
}node;

typedef struct{

    int id;
    double label;
    double distance;
}info;
```

and this function:

```
//KNN ALGORITH IMPEMANTATION

void knn(int k , int nep  ,  node *dataS , node *dataR , info **result)
{

double distance; 
#pragma omp parallel for private(distance) lastprivate(dataR)
for(int i=0;i<nep;i++){
    int count=0;
    for(int j=0;j<nep;j++){ 
        distance = calculate_distance(dataS+i ,dataR+j);
        if(result[i][k-1].distance==0.0)
        {   
            if(distance!=0)
            {
                if (count==k-1)
                {
                    result[i][count].id=dataR[count].id;
                    #pragma omp critical
                        result[i][count].label=dataR[count].label;
                    result[i][count].distance=distance;
                    qsort(result[i], k , sizeof(info) ,(compfn)compare);
                }
                else
                {
                    result[i][count].id=dataR[count].id;
                    #pragma omp critical
                        result[i][count].label=dataR[count].label;
                    result[i][count].distance=distance;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(distance!=0 && distance<result[i][k-1].distance)
            {
                #pragma omp critical
                {   
                    result[i][k-1].id = dataR[j].id;
                    result[i][k-1].distance=distance;
                    result[i][k-1].label=dataR[j].label;
                    qsort(result[i], k , sizeof(info) ,(compfn)compare);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
```

if I run it serial everything is fine, but if I run it parallel, I don't get the right output.

The real weird thing is that if i change the second struct to this :

```
typedef struct{

    int id;
    node point;
    double distance;
}info;
```

and make the necessary modification like this:

```
{

result[i][count].id = dataR[count].id;

result[i][count].point.label = dataR[count].label;

result[i][count].distance = distance;

qsort(result[i], k , sizeof(info) ,(compfn)compare);

}
```

Everything is fine.

Really what's going on?

Comment: Your second version appears to permit alignment without padding, which is good for performance.  The padding should break the code only if you neglect to use consistent compiler options regarding padding throughout.

Comment: So because i am new in programing, what can i do to use the first struct right?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, particularly the pointer layout of `result` is missing. Please construct a [mcve]. `lastprivate` doesn't work like you may think 1) It applies to the pointer, not the value 2) private variables are uninitialized.